# jhbuild system dependencies

Tags: dependencies, gnome, jhbuild

Whenever I build any `Gnome` application using `jhbuild` I get a lot of packages which are required. For example for the following command:

```
jhbuild sysdeps --install bijiben
```

Following errors appear:

```
W: Circular dependencies detected: bijiben -> appstream-glib -> gdk-pixbuf -> glib -> gvfs -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: bijiben -> appstream-glib -> gdk-pixbuf -> glib -> glib-networking -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: bijiben -> appstream-glib -> gdk-pixbuf -> glib -> dconf -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: bijiben -> appstream-glib -> glib -> dconf -> gtk+ -> adwaita-icon-theme -> gtk+

System installed packages which are new enough:
//ALL THE INSTALLED PACKAGES 
Required packages:
    System installed packages which are too old:
        xcb (xcb.pc, required=1.10, installed=1.8.1)
        p11-kit (p11-kit-1.pc, required=0.19.0, installed=0.12)
        libnl-route (libnl-route-3.0.pc, required=3.2.7, installed=3.2.3)
        gnutls (gnutls.pc, required=3.1, installed=2.12.14)
        libnl (libnl-3.0.pc, required=3.2.7, installed=3.2.3)

    No matching system package installed:
    //ALL THE NOT MATCHING INSTALLED PACKAGES 

    Optional packages: (JHBuild will build the missing packages)
    System installed packages which are too old:
        iso-codes (iso-codes.pc, required=3.51, installed=3.31)
        xtrans (xtrans.pc, required=1.3.5, installed=1.2.6)
        fontconfig (fontconfig.pc, required=2.11.1, installed=2.8.0)`
```

It then searches these packages via apt-file(which i installed earlier) and i get  this:

```
I: Installing dependencies on system: rdflib WebKit1 xmlto xcb-xkb spamassassin polkit-agent polkit-gobject poppler libyaml libarchive wayland-egl mtdev egl ragel enchant sqlite3 doxygen liboauth libproxy dbus-glib libsystemd highlight libsystemd-daemon gbm libsystemd-login rapper xorg-macros libgphoto2 libicu libcanberra bogofilter libnl-genl libical libndp
I: Using apt-file to search for providers; this may be slow.  Please wait.
I: No native package found for xcb-xkb (/xcb-xkb.pc)
I: No native package found for libsystemd (/libsystemd.pc)
I: No native package found for libsystemd-daemon (/libsystemd-daemon.pc)
I: No native package found for libsystemd-login (/libsystemd-login.pc)
I: No native package found for libicu (/icu-i18n.pc)
I: No native package found for libndp (/libndp.pc)
I: Installing: libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev libpolkit-agent-1-dev libpolkit-gobject-1-dev libpoppler-glib-dev libarchive-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libmtdev-dev cedarview-graphics-drivers libenchant-dev libsqlite3-dev liboauth-dev libproxy-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libgbm-dev xutils-dev libgphoto2-2-dev libcanberra-gtk-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libical-dev python-rdflib xmlto spamassassin libyaml-dev ragel doxygen highlight raptor-utils bogofilter-bdb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-drivers (= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7) or
                             libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-quantal but it is not going to be installed or
                             libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-raring but it is not going to be installed or
                             libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-saucy but it is not going to be installed or
                             libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MYPCNAME/.local/bin/jhbuild", line 32, in <module>
    jhbuild.main.main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/MYPCNAME/jhbuild/jhbuild/jhbuild/main.py", line 151, in main
    rc = jhbuild.commands.run(command, config, args, help=lambda: print_help(parser))
  File "/home/MYPCNAME/jhbuild/jhbuild/jhbuild/commands/__init__.py", line 183, in run
    return cmd.execute(config, args, help)
  File "/home/MYPCNAME/jhbuild/jhbuild/jhbuild/commands/__init__.py", line 52, in execute
    return self.run(config, options, args, help)
  File "/home/MYPCNAME/jhbuild/jhbuild/jhbuild/commands/sysdeps.py", line 207, in run
    installer.install(uninstalled)
  File "/home/MYPCNAME/jhbuild/jhbuild/jhbuild/utils/systeminstall.py", line 382, in install
    subprocess.check_call(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkexec', 'apt-get', 'install', 'libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev', 'libpolkit-agent-1-dev', 'libpolkit-gobject-1-dev', 'libpoppler-glib-dev', 'libarchive-dev', 'libegl1-mesa-dev', 'libmtdev-dev', 'cedarview-graphics-drivers', 'libenchant-dev', 'libsqlite3-dev', 'liboauth-dev', 'libproxy-dev', 'libdbus-glib-1-dev', 'libgbm-dev', 'xutils-dev', 'libgphoto2-2-dev', 'libcanberra-gtk-dev', 'libnl-genl-3-dev', 'libical-dev', 'python-rdflib', 'xmlto', 'spamassassin', 'libyaml-dev', 'ragel', 'doxygen', 'highlight', 'raptor-utils', 'bogofilter-bdb']' returned non-zero exit status 100
```

I even tried to sudo-apt get these packages but it says:

```
E: Unable to locate package rdflib
E: Unable to locate package WebKit1
E: Unable to locate package xcb-xkb
E: Unable to locate package polkit-agent
E: Unable to locate package polkit-gobject
E: Unable to locate package poppler
E: Unable to locate package libyaml
E: Unable to locate package libarchive
E: Unable to locate package wayland-egl
```

Now I'm unable to build any of the gnome application due to this problem.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 and jhbuild 3.12.0

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the development packages on your system, for example on Fedora I use `sudo yum install libarchive-devel` and similar for the other required packages.  On Ubuntu it's probably something like `sudo apt-get install libarchive-dev`.

As for the `System installed packages which are too old:`, I think you will need to get your hands on the newer versions of these packages.

Comment: I tried with sudo apt but nothing happened so i downloaded package from package manager but still the issue is not solved.

Comment: Yup, `JHBuild` definitely is lacking a way of nicely building and installing locally those non-Gnome system dependencies... :(